# What data type do I store 16 digit number into database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, types

I am new to C#, so sorry if this is an easy question.
I have a database connected to my datagrid via MS-Access. I have the user input the information and save it to the database. I am having a problem where the "CARD NUMBER" cannot be 16 digits, as it throws an error for data type. thank you in advance!

```
OleDbCommand updateQuery = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Profiles ([PROFILE NAME],[LOGIN EMAIL],[PASSWORD],[FULL NAME],[CARD NUMBER],[EXP MONTH],[EXP YEAR],CVV) VALUES(@name1,@email,@pass,@name2,@card,@expm,@expy,@cvv)", connection);

updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@name1", OleDbType.Variant).Value = textBox4.Text; //Profile Name
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.Variant).Value = textBox2.Text; //Email
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.Variant).Value = textBox3.Text;  //Pass
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@name2", OleDbType.Variant).Value = textBox1.Text; //Full Name
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@card", OleDbType.VarNumeric).Value = textBox5.Text;  //CardNumber
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@expm", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = comboBox1.Text; //EXPMonth
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@expy", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = comboBox2.Text; //EXPYear
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@cvv", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = textBox7.Text;   //CVV

updateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Profile Saved");
this.Close();
RefreshDBConnection();
```

Note: I changed my code to:

```
updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@card", OleDbType.VarNumeric).Value = textBox5.Text;  //CardNumber
```

and now it throws an overflow error. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Are you going to do arithmetic with that number? If not, just store it as a string.

Comment: How do I store as a string though?

Comment: The same way you store `name1`.

Comment: FYI it's possible to change the name of a text box, so you can give it a name that is more clear than `textBox4` etc.

Comment: I then get the error 'Overflow' @Stijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the datatype in db, if it is int!!! change it to BigInt and it will work :)

Comment: Note that BigInt support is only available in Access 2016 and later.

Comment: BigInt isn't an option, only Number. Maybe I can save it as a later version? instead of a .mbd file

Comment: I strongly recommend not using BigInt for external applications. Like Stijn said, it's Access 2016 only, but also only later builds of Access 2016, and the Access Database Engine Redistributable is behind in versioning. Obviously, it's accdb only.

Comment: I changed it from number to long text and it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

Using *BigInt* will cause severe limitations as already noted, and using *Long Text* (Note field) is the *worst* thing you could do.

So, either use *Short Text* or *Decimal* set to hold at least 16 digits:

[image]

Comment: What's bad about using a long text?, and I only have short text, long text, and  number options on my ms access file.

Comment: [Here is one reason](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html), @caden-buckelew. Others could be found in that link.

Comment: No index is another. You can put it: There is not a single good reason to use Long Text to hold 16 characters.